# Software to track CPU by process in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance, logging

I need to track CPU by process in Windows 7 and log results in a file.

How could I do this please?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Powershell, there are multiple options depending on what you want to do:

To log the CPU % of a specific process:

```
PS C:\Users\mmoor> $A=Get-Process
PS C:\Users\mmoor> $A[0].Name
AcroRd32
PS C:\Users\mmoor> $A[0].CPU
3.9156251
PS C:\Users\mmoor> "$($A[0].Name) --- $($A[0].CPU)" >> .\ProcessCPU.Log
```

You could also just send the output of Get-Process to a file:

```
PS C:\Users\mmoor> Get-Process >> .\ProcessCPU.Log
```

You could create a schedule task that runs a script like this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Process Explorer can do this, although you can only create dump files for individual processes. It does provide an easy way to view all running processes though.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx